# How can I identify acceptor and donor atoms using BioPython?

Tags: python, proteins, small-molecules

I know how to traverse through structures, models, residues, and atoms in a protein chain using BioPython (which is very easy).

How can I identify donor and acceptor atoms in a chain?

Comment: donor/acceptor belongs to the main chain (MC) or side chain (SC) of amino acids ??

Comment: @pippo1980, side chain. My target is to measure the distance between donor and acceptor atoms.

Comment: Ligand or hydrogen atoms of other side chains ? Just trying to put it into a perspective

Comment: I guess once you know coordinates of each putative donor and acceptor, you calculate the distances between all the possible pairs and take the ones under a threshold. My PhD examiner was blabbing about right geometry too … but we were talking about X-ray crystallography no way to know where  the hydrogens are and a kind of middle resolution so … but remember geometry is important too

Comment: Here a informative link https://www.biostars.org/p/182325/ this links to another post : most software simply looks for donor + acceptor pairs separated by an appropriate distance and bond angle.

Comment: @pippo1980, How does DSSP/STRIDE help in finding donor/acceptors? They are just supposed to detect secondary structures, no?

Comment: Auch you got me !!! Used STRIDE to assign secondary on my models !!! Don’t know how pdf validate nowadays secondary structure signatures : here about stride http://webclu.bio.wzw.tum.de/stride/stride.pdf

Comment: DSSP. Dictionary of Secondary Structure of Proteins (DSSP) assigns eight state secondary structure using hydrogen bonds alone. DSSP defines a hydrogen bond where the bond energy is below -0.5 kcal/mol based on a Coulomb approximation of the hydrogen bond energy.

Comment: My hydrogen bonding problem was about Ligand —> side chain dono/acceptor. Now you can point to new way to asses that for ligand interaction too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hydrogen bond donor heavy atom is one that is protonated, while the acceptor has a lone pair. If you talking about amino acids, then it's simple as they are fixed.

| atom name | description | role | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `N` | backbone nitrogen | donor | SS |
| `CA` | backbone Cα | apolar |  |
| `C` | backbone carboxyl C | sterically hindered and electrophilic | nucleophilic attack |
| `O` | backbone carboxyl O | acceptor | SS |
| `CB` etc. | sidechain carbons | apolar |  |
| `OXT` | C-terminal oxygen | acceptor | may be protonated especially if a membrane embedded C-terminus |
| Serine's `OG` / Threonine's `OG1` | sidechain hydroxyl | donor | SS: may form ST turns. Fairly uncommon: may be a donor |
| Asp `OD1`/`OD2`/Asn `OD1` | sidechain carboxyl/amide O | acceptor | SS: may form Asx turns |
| Glu `OG1`/`OG2`/Gln `OG1` | sidechain carboxyl/amide O | acceptor |  |
| Lysine `NZ` | sidechain amine | donor |  |
| Asn `ND2` / Gln `NG2` | terminal admide N | donor | the direction of an Asn/Gln may be accidentally filled if manually assigned as N/O have the same density in X-ray crystals |

Water can be both a donor and an acceptor.
Two charged residues form a salt bridge more so than a hydrogen bond, because the interaction is driven by the Coulomb electrostatic forces of the two heavy atoms.

Comment: *A hydrogen bond donor heavy atom is one that is protonated, while the acceptor has a lone pair.* -- Does this apply to BioPython's `Atom` object? I mean, can I test or search it using BioPython?

Comment: Yeah nah. A heavy atom is an atom that diffracts under X-ray crystallography —not hydrogens. The `Atom` instance is a graph network node representation of any atom. It may be a hydrogen —_in silico_ protonated, neutron diffraction or 1H NMR. Technically to the most pedantically punctilious level, it could be virtual (e.g. Drude particle)...

Comment: So, can I use your supplied information and apply them on a PDB file via BioPython and extract donor and acceptor atom info from that PDB file?

Comment: Totally — assuming a pair is within about 3Å

Comment: So, if I can extract donor and acceptor atom-related info, can I predict Hydrogen bonds in this way?

Comment: Completely... as said somewhere else though it is way easier working in dihedral space and assigning the SS by Ramachandran plot bins, e.g. see ABEGO bins in SI Fig 1 of https://www.nature.com/articles/s41594-018-0141-6#MOESM1 —however, looking at the hydrogen bonds is more precise as you can better assign the correct type of turns.

Comment: @MatteoFerla so treshold for distance would be  about 3Å, does this change with resolution of the stucture ? what about the bond geometry (https://academic.oup.com/peds/article/15/5/359/1508259)?

Comment: @user366312 I guess you should add hydrogens to your pdb first

Comment: @pippo1980, *I guess you should add hydrogens to your pdb first* --- that option has been forbidden by my P.I. According to him, this adds too much noise to the generated data.

Comment: 2.8Å is an ideal, >3.2Å is weak. Mathematically the [Lenard-Jones term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) is used in thermodynamic simulations —in the wiki page you can see the potential plateaus quickly.  Sure, the true distance will be marginally affected by the b-factors of the atoms (both anisotropic/isotropic) but in solution the distance is likely a distribution (i.e. the atoms wobbling around).